# draggable and resizable attributes are not working for primefaces datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a datatable for displaying the result being originated on the basis of various parameters selected on the same panel. I have attached the snap-shot of datatable.

Datatable maybe containing multiple rows. It may look you all cluttered at this movement but I am trying to improve it.[image: datatable]

I have tried to use draggable and resizable attributes of primefaces datatable as below but those are not working. I am not able to expand and drag the columns across the datatable:

```
<p:dataTable id="tbl" var="item"
        value="#{cc.attrs.searchAndConsultSecuritiesEntriesResultsPanel.results}"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
        paginator="true" rows="20" style="margin-bottom:20px"
        sortMode="multiple" draggableColumns="true" draggableRows="true"
        resizableColumns="true">
```

Comment: any patience please... And did you read [ask], [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info? There is at least very important info missing... hint: this functionality is not supported in PrimeFaces 0.9.6

Comment: @Kukeltje,I am using Primefaces version 5.x

Comment: @Kukeltje,what about this - http://www.primefaces.org/downloads

Comment: @Kukeltje  Sorry for confusion but I meant 5.3

Comment: Did you try all options separately? (like they work in the showcase?). Tried less columns? And 'not working' is not smart. Any errors client-side? etc.. you should investigate more yourself

Comment: Yes @Kukeltje..I have tried to use horizontal scrollbar with setting the width for each column individually but its decreasing the overall width of table itself and there is no impact over the individual width of columns.I have seen the demos of p:datatable at primefaces website but they are not using any attribute such as resizable and dragabble,surprisingly.I have tried to alter the table just by giving the individual widths of columns.With less columns(10-15) I can see results are less cluttered though I have 35 columns overall.I am not getting any error at client side.

Comment: @Kukeltje..according to my requirement I need to see all the 35 columns clearly over datatable.I can use a horizontal scrollbar if needed

Comment: Nonsense, there ARE resizable and draggable demo's